# Having issues sending ® character through AJAX request

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, character-encoding, yui

I have simple asp.net web application which is using YUI for Ajax request. Application read text from text box and send AJAX request to server. Following is the code

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="txt" name="txt" type="text" value="[Enter some value]" />
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="button" />
    </div>
    <div id="out"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

following is the client script that initializes the Ajax request

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("btn", "click", function(evt) {
        var url = "Server.aspx?type=test&txt=" + document.getElementById("txt").value;
        var btn = document.getElementById("out");
        var cObj = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('GET', url, {
            success: function(o) {
                btn.innerHTML += "<div>" + o.responseText + " = " + o.responseText.charCodeAt(0) + "</div>";
            },
            failure: function(o) {
                confirm("Its failure");
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
});
```

What i do in application is accept character entered by user, save it to db and write it to Ajax response. System does not support Unicode (database).

Now my problem is that when "Registered" ® character (0174) is entered in the text box and sent to server i am getting #65533 which is not what user has entered on the text box. Also ® this character is not Unicode character then why this behavior.

Comment: What character encoding do you use? You noted that it isn't any of the Unicode encodings, but you didn't specify which you *do* use.

Comment: Do you mean content-encoding OR content-type of the Ajax request which is sent ?

Comment: There are probably many different encoding (settings) involved, and all of them might matter, e.g. DB encoding, encoding of page delivered to client, encoding when working on server side. Btw., is your problem actually limited to the "Registered" character alone, or are there any other characters also showing this problem?

Comment: Currently i am only seeing it for "register" but i suspect that same problem might be there for some other characters like this

Comment: It looks like the UTF encoding was working as expected but javascript escape() function was all that was causing the issues. I have found that the application where we have this problem that parameters were encoded using escape() function was causing issues to ® character. We changed it to encodeUriComponent() and that resolved the issue. Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

Forget about configuration issues, your problem is probably related to your editor and the file encoding it's using to save your files. It's not enough to set the character encoding, sometimes it doesn't even matter, you have to save the files themselves in an encoding thats supports the character set, for example: utf-8 without BOM, get an editor where you can see this information. Of course there could be a lot happening between in your web server, data base server(assuming you are using one) and client. Checkout the default character in the whe web server, the database and the file encoding your editor is using to save the files.

Answer (score 1):

Deducing from the tags you set, the backend is programmed in asp.net? Check what encoding you are working with there (see e.g. [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/ssadasivuni/archive/2005/01/19/355935.aspx)). Your problem sounds a lot like that would differ from what you deliver to the client (see server settings).

Comment: Thanks for this i tried adding globalizatioin in web.config but it not worked for me. Any more inputs on this ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the server part answering the AJAX requests receives the text, puts it into the database and sends it back; the sent back value arrives incorrectly; but have you checked the values on server, are they still correct?

Comment: Not they too are incorrect ... i checked values on server while debugging and content-type is coming as application/x-www-form-urlencoded; utf-8;

Comment: Difficult thing for me to digest is that current code produces correct behavior on Mozill however IE it does not work i mean generates "?" symbol. Then after lots of content type trials i changed method to POST and it started working well. But its test application when i tried fix on actual server it still failed.

Comment: Sounds like your test and your production server are configured differently. AFAIK, most browsers send back data in the encoding that the page was delivered in (or marked to be in, or what they believe it is in) - check that the encoding your server outputs (for ASP.NET the configuration in my answer should actually apply) and what's given in the html output (charset in meta tag) matches and is the one you also expect back from the browser.